# What does activated carbon do to gasoline vapor?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, hydrocarbons, absorption

What does activated carbon do to gasoline vapor? After the vapor is absorbed into a charcoal EVAP canister, what is left to be sent to the engine?

My question is in reference to the work of Tom Ogle and the carburetor he made in the 1970's, and I just want to find out if his invention is plausible.

---

Fuel enters the ignition chamber while still in its liquid form. 
http://fuel-efficient-vehicles.org/energy-news/?page_id=787
I want to know if this is possible

Comment: The evap canister is only meant to trap vapor in the tank so it does not come out when the gas cap is removed. Vapor is not sent to the engine - liquid is.

Comment: the evap system is designed to keep in fuel vapor and then send the fuel vapor to the engine once it reaches atmospheric conditions. The thing is by sending gas in its liquid form to be ignited is wasteful, since it only burns as a vapor.

Comment: Vaporizing the fuel is the fuel injector's job, directly on the piston. Or, on old cars, in the carburetor (on top of the engine). The fuel pump is there to transport liquid to the engine (injector or carburetor). If you cut the fuel line from the pump to the engine compartment, you get liquid coming out. If you open up a carburetor while the engine is running you see liquid being sprayed in to it.

Comment: Actually, gas vapour from the fuel tank is directed to the engine, as a means of disposal to avoid it escaping to the air (environmental consideration). The engine operates on a supply of fuel delivered in liquid form up to the point it is mixed with air in either the carburetor or at the fuel injector. But fuel evaporates in the tank; rather than venting to the atmosphere, this fuel vapor is directed to the induction system so the engine will burn it rather than release it unburned.